# How to embed youtube video from a channel?

Tags: youtube

Youtube Video shows   "This video contains content from ...., who has blocked it from display on this website".

I am using

```
   <iframe height="166" frameborder="0" width="306" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SidK27PA1Wg/?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;border=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

How will I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is:

```
"This video contains content from ...., who has blocked it from display on this website"
```

That means the user disabled embedding the video. It's an option you've when uploading a video. So it's not possible to embed that video